# React App deployment on Heroku: Loading paused after npm package installation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I have a web app that uses Express backend and React frontend. The `heroku-postbuild` script in my `package.json` is as follows:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "concurrently \"node server.js\" \"cd client && npm install && npm run build\""
```

When I `git push heroku master` all seems to be fine until the process is halted at:

```
remote:        [1] cd client && npm install && npm run build exited with code 0
```

It had been at this state for about 30 minutes before I `ctrl`+`c` to terminate. Any idea as to why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you, becuase I tried and it is working fine

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install --prefix client        && npm run build --prefix client"  
  }
```

for more details follow this [article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-with-an-express-server-on-heroku-32244fe5a250/).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by doing what @iamwebkalakaar suggested:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
```

and, additionally, setting the start script in my `Procfile` to:

```
web: npm run server
```

which refers to the script in my `package.json`:

```
server: "node server.js"
```

My takeaway is that the `heroku-postbuild` should contain anything relevant to React (package installation and build) and the `Procfile` script should run the express server.